# FlickrApi exception: Photo not found on calling photo.getSizes()

Tags: python, api, flickr

I get a `flickrapi.exceptions.FlickrError: Error: 1: Photo not found` exception in the code below, at this line:

```
sizes_element =  self.flickr.photos_getSizes(k_id = id)
```

However, according to me the `photo_id` that I am passing is correct.

```
import flickrapi

class FlickrDownloader():

def __init__(self,key,secret):
   self.api_key = key
   self.secret = secret
   self.flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(self.api_key,self.secret)

def getUrls(self):
    self.photos = self.flickr
    self.urlList = []

    #get a list of photos
    photo_element = self.flickr.photos_search(tags = 'flowers',per_page = '10')
    #get and iterator over elements
    photo_iter = photo_element.iter('photo')
    self.i = 0

    for photo in photo_iter:
        #get the photo id
        id = photo.attrib['id']
        print id
        #get the different sizes of photo
        sizes_element =  self.flickr.photos_getSizes(k_id = id)
        #get an interator
        sizes_iter = sizes_element.iter('size')

        #iterate over the sizes
        for size in sizes_iter:
            #check if its original size
            if size.attrib['label'] == 'Original':
                self.urlList.append(size.attrib['source'])

    return self.urlList
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flickr.photos.getSizes call doesn't take a `k_id` parameter. Check [the Flickr documentation](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html), it shows that you need to pass the photo ID using the `photo_id` parameter. You need to get the parameter names right, otherwise Flickr doesn't know what to do with them.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!